# How to export big data from MS SQL database to Excel file in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, export-to-excel

One of web applications I am working on it was developed in *Classic ASP*.

It was on local server now we moved it to **AZURE**

It is not so powerful as **.NET** web applications.Mostly popular problems I am facing with is export data for reporting .

What is the solutions to export data from connected database to *excel format* or *CSV*?

Select query includes more than 50.000 rows I do not want it crash

Answer (score 0):

Lets start :I will just create simple example with connecting to simple table .

```
<%@  language="VBScript" %> 
<%Response.Buffer = false%>  

<!--Time out for database connection-->
<% 
    Server.ScriptTimeout = 300
%>

<%
response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment;filename=EnterFileName.xls"
response.CharSet = "UTF-8"


set Conn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Conn.open Application("DBConnectionString") 
conn.CommandTimeout=1400 
set Rs = server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
set RsSelect = server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset") 

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Countries "  
Rs.open strQuery, Conn, 1, 2
%>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Code</strong></td> 
    </tr>
    <%
            do while not Rs.eof
    %>
    <tr> 
        <td><%=Rs("Name")%></td>
        <td><%=Rs("Code")%></td> 
    </tr>
                <% Rs.movenext    
                loop %>
</table>

<%
rs.Close
set rs = nothing
Conn.Close
Set conn = nothing
%>
```

if you set time out correctly even your export includes more than 50.000 rows with more than columns in each you will get export and it will not crash.